# Notepad++ Regex to search part of a line with a certain structure

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm needing a Regex to extract in SQL only `(XX, 3, 57, 1, XX, 'CONTENT TO EXTRACT')`

I need a find/replace code to transform a code like this

```
(808, 3, 43, 0, 82, 'coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-araca-sp'),
(809, 3, 57, 1, 82, 'coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-araca-sp.html'),
(810, 3, 57, 0, 82, 'coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-araca-sp.html'),
(814, 3, 41, 0, 83, 'Coroa de Flores Cemitério Baeta Neves - São Bernardo'),
(815, 3, 43, 0, 83, 'coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-baeta-neves'),
(816, 3, 46, 0, 83, 'Coroa de Flores Velório Cemitério Baeta Neves - Cesta e Flor'),
(817, 3, 49, 0, 83, 'PRODUCTS'),
(818, 3, 58, 0, 83, NULL),
(819, 3, 61, 0, 83, NULL),
(820, 3, 57, 1, 83, 'coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-baeta-neves.html'),
(821, 3, 57, 0, 83, 'coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-baeta-neves.html'),
(822, 3, 41, 0, 84, 'Coroa de Flores Cemitério Camilópolis - Santo André'),
(823, 3, 43, 0, 84, 'coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-camilopolis-santo-andre'),
(824, 3, 46, 0, 84, 'Coroa Flores Velório Camilópolis Santo André - Cesta e Flor'),
(825, 3, 49, 0, 84, 'PRODUCTS'),
(826, 3, 58, 0, 84, NULL),
(827, 3, 61, 0, 84, NULL),
(828, 3, 57, 1, 84, 'coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-camilopolis-santo-andre.html'),
(829, 3, 57, 0, 84, 'coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-camilopolis-santo-andre.html'),
(830, 3, 41, 0, 85, 'Coroa de Flores Velório  Parque da Cantareira - São Paulo'),
(831, 3, 43, 0, 85, 'coroa-flores-velorio-parque-cantareira-sp'),
(832, 3, 46, 0, 85, 'Coroa de Flores Velório Pq da Cantareira SP - Cesta e Flor'),
(833, 3, 49, 0, 85, 'PRODUCTS'),
(834, 3, 58, 0, 85, NULL),
(835, 3, 61, 0, 85, NULL),
```

in something like

```
coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-veenter code herelorio-cemiterio-araca-sp.html

coroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-baeta-neves.html

oroas-flores-para-velorio/coroa-flores-velorio-sao-paulo/coroa-flores-velorio-cemiterio-camilopolis-santo-andre.html
```

the find needs to search something that have the structure

```
(???, 3, 57, 1, ???, 'CONTENT')
```

and the replace needs the

```
CONTENT
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you could use regex for that.

Comment: A simple approach, find `\((?:[^,)]*,){5}'([^')]*)'\)`, replace `$1`

Comment: I don't have notepad++, but the regex could be: `\(\d{3}, 3, 57, 1, \d{2}, \'(.*)\'\),` and replace with `$1` or `\1` depending on your version.

Comment: Emanuel, I can help, but please share what you have tried. It is important to know what you used to avoid any misunderstanding of the requirements.

Comment: @sln: This will match all lines, OP wants only those that have `3, 57, 1` in them.

Comment: @drewyupdrew: OP wants to delete lines that haven't `3, 57, 1`

Comment: Thanks, Drew, Wiktor and Toto, Really appreciate the help, but none of the codes works at my case. Another ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\(\d+, 3, 57, 1, \d+, '([^']+)'\),$|^.+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                       : begining of line
  \(                    : an open parenthesis
  \d+, 3, 57, 1, \d+,   : some digits, then "3, 57, 1" then some digits
  '                     : single quote
    ([^']+)             : group 1, every thing that is not a quote
  '                     : single quote
  \),                   : close parenthesis and a comma
$                       : end of line
  |                     : OR    
^                       : begining of line
  .+                    : 1 or more any character
$                       : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1       : group 1, it will replace lines that don't match with empty string.
```

Comment: Really Thanks, For the intention of really helping, and explaining the code, but unfortunately did not work in my case.
And I did not give Downvote.

Comment: @Emanuel: What doesn't work? What do you get? I tested with Npp 7.2.2 and it works. Did you check `Regular expression` and NOT check `. matches newline`?

Comment: Where do you learn this? I really need this, and how i can upvote your answer? 

Its showing this message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

But, really thanks man!

Comment: @Dan: Your case is much more difficult than this one. I'll have a look.